# Tree View using jQuery API

Tags: jquery

I have the following data inside a text file.

```
C:\Test\A
C:\Test\B
C:\Test\C
C:\Test\A\A1
C:\Test\B\B1
C:\Test\C\C1
```

How can I make the records above to look like this on a HTML web page:

```
 C:\Test\A
          A1\...
         B
          B1\...
         C
          C1\...
```

through some jQuery tree view API?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have three questions here: (1) how to read a text file in JavaScript - we would need more information on where the file is located; (2) how to parse the data; and (3) how to display the results as a tree - [this page lists some solutions](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/tree/), for instance. Please clarify where your issues are.

Comment: I addition to the comment by @KenY-N, I would suggest you use server side code to parse the file and convert it to JSON. You can use that JSON data to be used in the browser. You can then use this: http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/

Comment: First off all, I would like to thank you all for the response, and sorry for the vague question of mine: Here is my current situation : Business owner instructed me to get all directories from PC 1, so I've done this command on from the cmd : "dir /s/a/b/t  > D:/results.txt, and actually Im using an MVC project to convert the lines from the text file to a JSON format, but my problem as you can see is that each line repeats the node before the new one at the next line, which causes a duplicate on my JS tree view.